# Ivy Need to retrieve files by organization

Tags: ant, ivy

We have a project we're converting from Ant to Ant with Ivy. It's a bit mess and includes Java, Coldfusion, and renaming elements to lowercase.

I've gotten it pretty much working, except for one issue. I need to retrieve all of the jars with an embedded version string. However, certain jar files (organisation="org.jboss.seam") need to be retrieved without the revision numbers. that is, I need

```
commons-beanutil-1.6.jar (or whatever it is)
```

but

```
jboss-seam-io.jar
```

I tried with `<include>` and `<exclude>`

```
<ivy:retrieve log="${ivy.log}"
    pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
    conf="*">
    <exclude org="org.jboss.seam"/>
</ivy:retrieve>
<ivy:retrieve log="${ivy.log}"
    pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]"
    conf="*">
    <include org="org.jboss.seam"/>
</ivy:retrieve>
```

But `<ivy:retrieve>` doesn't take include and excludes. I think it might be possible with mappers, but the Ivy documentation is very sparse.

Anyone has any ideas how to retrieve the `jboss-seam` files with one Ivy pattern, but everything else (including the dependencies for the `jboss-seam` jars) with another Ivy pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I finally figured it out. First of all, it's regex***p***mapper and not *regexmapper*. Then, I found I had to put the full path name in, and do the mapper twice, once for the `jboss-seam` stuff, and once for everythign else:

```
<ivy:retrieve log="${ivy.log}"
    pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
    conf="*">
    <firstmatchmapper>
        <regexpmapper from="${lib.dir}/([^/]*)/(jboss-seam.*)-([0-9].*)\.jar"
             to="${lib.dir}/\1/\2.jar"/>
        <regexpmapper  from="(.*)"
             to="\1"/>
    </firstmatchmapper>
</ivy:retrieve>
```